# Printf tab character as hex

Tags: linux, bash, printf

In a restricted shell i have only access to execute printf (no awk, hexdump, xxd, ...), so i used this script to print a file as hex:

```
a=$(<file.txt)
for ((i=0;i<${#a};i++));
do c=${a:$i:1}; 
    if [[ $c == ' ' ]]; then printf "%X" \'\ \'; 
    elif [[ $c == $'\r' ]]; then printf "%X" \'\r\'; 
    elif [[ $c == $'\t' ]]; then printf "%X" \'\t\'; 
    elif [[ $c == $'\n' ]]; then printf "%X" \'\n\'; 
    else printf %02x \'${a:$i:1};
    fi; 
done
```

issue:
last line (printf %02x \'${a:$i:1}) does not work for some character like \s,\r,\n,\t,...
i handle space character with (printf "%X" \'\ \') but does not work for \r,\t and \n

```
printf "%X" \'\t\' ---> 74
printf "%X" "'\t"  ---> 5C
printf "%X" \'$"\t"---> 5C
```

but it should return 09!

Comment: Please, check the update to my reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm getting 9 from

```
printf "%X" \'$'\t'
```

Quoting the expression should simplify the code, no ifs needed:

```
a=$(<file.txt)
for (( i=0 ; i < ${#a} ; i++ )) ; do
    c=${a:$i:1}
    printf %02x \'"$c"
done
```

Comment: Do have any suggestion to improve speed? for a file with few MB size it will print less than 10 byes per seconds!

Comment: @Giac: Rewrite it in a real programming language.

Comment: I don't have any alternative, my account has limited access (only some native commands). i want to generate hexdump of some binary files to copy those strings and convert it to real file on local machine. this is my scenario

Comment: @Giac bash doesn't seem to handle large strings efficiently, so if the file is big having the whole thing in a variable will slow processing down significantly. Try reading and processing small chunks at a time by adding an outer loop: `while IFS= read -r -d '' -n 512 a; do` ...chorba's for loop goes here ... `done <file.txt`. Also, a warning: none of this is safe for binary data, because the shell doesn't allow null bytes in variables (or arguments, or much of anywhere else).

Comment: Actually, after a bit of testing it looks like the optimal number of characters to read at a time isn't 512 (the guess I put above), it's 1 (and skip the inner loop). So just use `while IFS= read -r -d '' -n 1 c; do printf "%02x " \'"$c"; done <file.txt`. A ~3MB file took about 2 minutes on my laptop.

Comment: @choroba : unfortunately there isn't these commands. @ Gordon Thanks it's work.